# Scroll text inside MultiAutoCompleteTextView programmatically

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

I want to create something similar to the Instagram search bar for messages, where I can add recipients as chips just pressing to the some user item from the suggestions list. My problem is the position of the cursor in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView. When I add last token, I want the text scroll a bit left to give area for the cursor to allow the user to type and see what he is typing. But in my case my cursor is on the border of the screen. It is not very convenient and looks not very good. The first image is the my implementation using https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete library. The second image is from the Instagram. Please, tell me any possible solutions how can I scroll text inside MultiAutoCompleteTextView programmatically?[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this then please share with us.

Comment: I've ended up with paddingRight = 20dp. It is not the same, but it worked for my needs.